# SQL getting the correct dataset using aggregate query

Tags: sql

[image: user table]

[image: calls table]

[image: sms]

so i have the user , calls, sms table , now i want to get the count of incoming and outgoing calls and sms per user

i have this query

```
select u.username,
        sum(case when c.type = 'incoming' then 1 else 0 end) as  incoming,
        sum(case when c.type = 'incoming' and status = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) as  answered,
        sum(case when c.type = 'outgoing' then 1 else 0 end) as  outgoing,
        sum(case when s.type = 'in'   then 1 else 0 end )  as sms
 from user u  
 join
      calls c
      on u.id = c.user_id
 join 
      sms s
      on u.id = s.user_id

 group by u.username;
```

and the result is this

[image]

incoming and outgoing in calls is correct but in sms the result is wrong in user sample ,it should be 1 in column sms and not 4

Comment: Simplify the query to debug, remove the group by and sum and see if the result is correct. I believe there is a problem in the `join`, such that it produces more `sms`.

Comment: i can't remove sum since i need the count of incoming and outgoing in calls and when i removed the group by it gives me one row for sample user

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the multiplication effect you are having with the joins, you can try aggregating the calls and sms tables separately by user, and then joining to these subqueries:

```
SELECT
    u.username,
    COALESCE(t1.incoming, 0) AS incoming,
    COALESCE(t1.answered, 0) AS answered,
    COALESCE(t1.outgoing, 0) AS outgoing,
    COALESCE(t2.sms, 0) AS sms
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        user_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'incoming' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  incoming,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.type = 'incoming' AND status = 'true'
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS answered,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.type = 'outgoing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS outgoing
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY user_id
) t1
    ON u.id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        user_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN s.type = 'in' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sms
    FROM sms
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON u.id = t2.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for this it's a bit long query is there a way to shorten this one?

Comment: @vladawtsu I can't think of a simpler solution which will give you the results you want.  I don't think that simply joining everything as you had originally tried will work, as you have already seen.